# Relationship between page and controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

Is it advisable to have multiple pages for 1 controller? 
Like for each Visualforce Page, they only have minimal process just like initializations only.

For example:
I have Apex Class TestPageController.

```
public with sharing class TestPageController{

   public TestPageController(){
      //did something
   }

   public PageReference initialize(){
      //do process for both page
     //getSomethingfromAPI1();  <--to be use for 1st page
     //getSomethingfromAPI2();  <--to be use for 2nd page
   }
}
```

Then Page1 and Page2 uses this controller.
Would it be okay or just have to use different controllers for each page? 
Can someone enlighten?

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can and the view state will be shared across pages, as long as you don't perform a redirect.. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm

Comment: Hmm but Page2 is a result of clicking something from Page1 but im not using setRedirect..so it's just okay right?

Comment: Yes it is okay as long as you dont use `setRedirect(true)`. And yes it is absolutely okay to use one controller for multiple pages for share a view state between those pages.